# print specific div content not showing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

i want to print specific div by javascript. it is working fine when printed without any html tag. but when use any html 
tag like p, h1 or h2 it is printed blank page.

here is my code

```
    @extends('layout.master')
    @section('content')
    <div class="separator-breadcrumb border-top">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header bg-secondary" style="padding: 7px 1.25rem">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-1">
                               <button onclick="printDiv('printMe')" class="btn btn-danger font-weight-700"> Print
                               </button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                 <div id="printMe" >
                       <div class="card-body">
                          <h1>
                            Print this only
                          </h1>
                      </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   @endsection
    @section('JScript')
      <script>
         function printDiv(divID) {
            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = divElements;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
        }
      </script>
  @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

try formating your code so it doesn't parse as HTML (replacing the '<' closing tags character with the unicode &lt ; , and also placing it within a

```
 tag, to preserve white space:
```

`// try changing from this :
var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = divElements;

// to this :
var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + divElements.replace(/</g, '&lt;') + '</pre>';`

Comment: I have already changed my code by your code but still not working !!